# Safe to delete default Attribute Groups?

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder, attribute-group, data-designer

On a new BU, when I open Data Designer in Contact Builder, there are already a few Attribute Groups defined.

[image: Data Designer]

Can I safely delete those circles and create my own? Will it have any impact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are system-generated Attribute Groups.

**You can not delete them.**

You only can delete Attribute Groups that you've created.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even noticed that!

Comment: Atleast you can try! Trial and Error!